# How to view sharding keys in mongodb shell?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

This might be a dummy question, but I cannot find any clue in all online doc.

For a already-built-up mongodb cluster, How can I find which **sharding key(s)** is used for given collecton?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As outlined in the [Sharding Administration Docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Administration), you can use `db.printShardingStatus()` to see this information.

For sharded collections it will print the key pattern.

Answer (score 15):

You can login to any "mongos" instance (or config server instance) on the cluster and query against the collections collection.

```
use config
db.collections.find()
```

You can also do this from any of the drivers since it's just like running a normal query. This collection stores information about all of the sharded collections in your cluster and which keys they are sharded on.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the normal status command.

```
sh.status()
```

Output copied from my shell for reference

```
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "Test1",  "primary" : "atlas-<hidden>",  "partitioned" : true,  "version" : {  "uuid" : UUID("<hidden>"),  "lastMod" : 1 } }
                Test1.TestCollection
                        shard key: { "location" : 1, "userid" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                atlas-<hidden>  172
```

Under databases section you will see the complete detail.